# Flash ActionScript 3: Reading text from a file

Tags: actionscript-3, file, flash, save

There's my problem: I want to load the data from a text file (Named "myText.txt") with Flash CS5.5 . It contains some lines, and I want to store these lines in an Array. This is what I've got from now:

```
var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest("myText.txt");
var myArray:Array = new Array();

myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadComplete(myArray));

function loadComplete(myArray:Array):Function {
    return function(e:Event):void {
        myArray = myLoader.data.split("\n");

        for(var i:int = 0; i < myArray.length; ++i){
            trace(myArray[i]);                         // To check if it works at this point
        }
    }
}

for(var i:int = 0; i < myArray.length; ++i){
    trace(myArray[i]);                                 // To check if it gets modified
}
```

The fact is that the fist part works, it loads the text file and it stores in `myArray`, and traces it; but it stores only in the local version of `myArray`, it doesn't modify the reference, so the `for` outside of the function doesn't trace anything.

I had read that Arrays were passed by reference in flash, so I don't understand why it doesn't work.

I would appreciate the help.

---

### **EDIT**

The thing now is that this is just a test file, I want this code to be in a function that I will use a lot. The ideal would be to have a static function in an AS Class File named "Utils", with other useful functions. The code of the "Utils.as" file would be like this:

```
package Include {

    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Utils {

        public function Utils() {
        }

        public static function fileToArray(path:String):Array {
            var linesArray = new Array();

            // Code to load the file stored in 'path' (the 'path' String
            // also has the name of the file in it), split by '\n' and store every line
            // in the 'linesArray' Array.
            // Example: path = "file:////Users/PauTorrents/Desktop/program/text.txt"

            return linesArray;
        }

        // other functions

    }

}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: the for loop at the bottom executes before the file has been loaded. Loading a file takes a little bit amount of time, but that time window is enough for the loop to execute. Also, because it's an async event.

Comment: For the second part of your question, how to implement depends on some things - the foremost in my mind would be if there would ever be a need to load more than one text file at once.  Also, should each load add to the same array? or return a new array?    It will have to be asynchronous no matter how you do it.

Comment: Sorry about the edit thing, I'm very new here.

My idea is to save all the file in the Array (split by "\n") and proceed with my own stuff to assign the corresponding attributes of the array to a class I made. The second part isn't the problem, I have solved this. But because of I made a class named "Team", I won't just open one team during the execution of the program.

I made a program similar to this one in C++, maybe this is confusing me a little bit.

The fact is that it will be opening one text file at a time, but it will open some different text files during the program.

Comment: Maybe it's just something like a database of Teams, with it's Coaches and Players. Every team is in a single text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things need addressing here.

First, **your for loop at the end will always run before the load completes, so it will never trace anything.**    AS3 does not lock the thread when a URLoader loads, so it will move on with the rest of the code in the block while it waits to load the file.

Second, it's really ugly returning an annonumous function as the result of your load complete handler.

Here is how I would do this:

```
var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest("myText.txt");
var myArray:Array = new Array();

myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadComplete, false, 0, true);

function loadComplete(e:Event):void{
    myArray = myLoader.data.split("\n");

    for(var i:int = 0; i < myArray.length; ++i){
        trace(myArray[i]);                         // To check if it works at this point
    }

    //now move on with the rest of your program/code
}
```